# Merge generated files from trunk into branch

Tags: svn, merge, code-generation

We are using a tool which generates source code. This source code is submitted into the trunk. New generate sessions are copied over the existing files. Problem is that when someone wishes to merge the trunk into a branch, you get conflicts (local add, incoming add upon merge).

What I want is: takes all the files from the trunk and copy them to my branch. Delete all files that are not in the trunk.

I can't find or think of an SVN and user friendly solution, so I'm hoping some of you will :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this very reason, you shouldn't keep generated files in Subversion (or any source code control system).

However, you are where you are.  You need to `svn del` the files you want to go away and `svn cp` the files you want in their place.  You can use URLs to the repository to avoid checking everything out and you can use `svn ls` on a directory URL to list files to find out what you need to delete.

Comment: How would that prevent conflicts during merges?

Comment: @sbi: if the file was copied from trunk and you are merging from trunk, there should be no conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and let you know my proceedings. It sounds reasonable.

Comment: Ok so this has been ages and currently I'm working at another job. I won't be looking into this somewhere soon. I'll accept this answser as an answer since it is the only answer with an answer (still following? :-p) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You should not check in generated files, only the sources from which they are generated.

Comment: Agreed, that's beyond my control however. Issues with licencing an so on...I'd still would like to create an easy, preferably automated, solution however ;-) Something to fool SVN in thinking that there are no conflicts on the generated files...

Comment: I don't think you can. If you do things you shouldn't do, you will have to live with the issues that lead them to be labeled as "shouldn't do".